How to categorise the assets for Candymachine?
I am making an NFT collection using Solana Metaplex candy machine. Here, I want to release the collection in 8 categories . So when I release the collection, the user are eligible to mint throughout any of the 8 categories. Each categories are going to have 500 assets assigned. Like for example, the assets are uploaded in this manner:
Cat A: 1-500,  
Cat B: 501-1000  
Cat C: 1001-1500  
Cat D: 1501-2000  
Cat E: 2001-2500  
Cat F: 2501-3000  
Cat G: 3001-3500  
Cat H: 3501-4000 

My question is how to arrange all the assets in such a manner that when the users mint, they are able to receive the NFTs from their particular bracket?
Let’s say, when user 1 mints an NFT from Cat C, so they should only receive the assets between 1001-1500.
In my candymachine, I have although added the labels to add the different categories. But I know, that when I am going to mint it, it is going to assign random assets for the NFTs that I will be minted.
As of now, my candymachine roughly looks like this:
{
  "tokenStandard": "pnft",
  "number": 10,
  "symbol": "ADF",
  "sellerFeeBasisPoints": 500,
  "isMutable": true,
  "isSequential": false,
  "ruleSet": "AQvYNMN2uZJWYPrBuMvyBbLyMDEee7mfafRZbBuPXxJ1",
  "creators": [
    {
      "address": "AQvYNMN2uZJWYPrBuMvyBbLyMDEee7mfafRZbBuPXxJ1",
      "share": 50
    },
    {
      "address": "AQvYNMN2uZJWYPrBuMvyBbLyMDEee7mfafRZbBuPXxJ1",
      "share": 50
    }
  ],
  "hiddenSettings": null,
  "uploadMethod": "null",
  "awsConfig": null,
  "nftStorageAuthToken": null,
  "shdwStorageAccount": null,
  "pinataConfig": pinata-key,
  "sdriveApiKey": null,
  "guards": {
    "default": {
      "botTax": {
        "value": 0.01,
        "lastInstruction": true
      }
    },
    "groups": [
      {
        "label": "trait #1",
        "guards": {
          "startDate": {
            "date": "2024-01-01 12:00:00 +0000"
          },
          "solPayment": {
            "value": 0.01,
            "destination": "AQvYNMN2uZJWYPrBuMvyBbLyMDEee7mfafRZbBuPXxJ1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "label": "trait #2",
        "guards": {
          "startDate": {
            "date": "2024-01-01 12:00:00 +0000"
          },
          "solPayment": {
            "value": 0.01,
            "destination": "AQvYNMN2uZJWYPrBuMvyBbLyMDEee7mfafRZbBuPXxJ1"
          }
        }
      }
///// 
/////
/// 6 more similar lables
/////
/////

      }
    ]
  }
}

Can someone please help me how to work here? I am going to upload the assets via IPFS on pinata.

so if i have category B so it will be 501 to 1000 but it would be random am i right?

Yeah, that is correct, it can be random, but should only should select from 501 to 1000.
